# WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager - "The client MUST NOT use more than one authentication method in each" Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to integrate wso2is-5.11.0 as the key manager for wso2am-4.1.0 and I followed the below documentation to set it up.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/

However, I'm getting the following error when the token endpoint is invoked.

```
{
    "error_description": "The client MUST NOT use more than one authentication method in each",
    "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

As per the documentation, this occurs due to the MutualTLS authenticator being enabled by default and therefore I added the following configuration for the deployment.toml file in wso2is-5.11.0 but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

```
[[event_listener]]
id = "mutual_tls_authenticator"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handler.clientauth.mutualtls.MutualTLSClientAuthenticator"
order = "158"
enable = false
```

A solution to resolve this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the following to the deployment.toml instead of the one mentioned in the doc.

```
[event.default_listener.mutual_tls_authenticator]
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handler.clientauth.mutualtls.MutualTLSClientAuthenticator"
order = "158"
enable = false
```